# Реализация :not(:only-child) или альтернативы

Tags: css

Задача реализовать разные условия для блока, содержащего один или несколько элементов. К примеру разное поведение flex-блока с одной картинкой (растягивается на всю ширину) или несколькими (выстраиваются попарно). Идеальным вариантом было бы использование проверки вроде `:not(:only-child)`.
Пробую так, но не срабатывает:

```
[class*=pic] img:not(:only-child) {
flex-basis: calc(100% / 2); 
max-width: calc(100% / 2); 
}
...
[class*=pic] img:only-child {
flex-basis: 100%;
width: 100%; 
max-width: 100%; 
}
```

В итоге одиночная картинка все равно подпадает под 50% (вероятно, из-за ошибки приоритетов).
До этого использовал рабочий, но более тяжеловесный способ: разные классы для одиночных и парных картинок. Но и у него было много подводных камней с унификацией общих стилей.
В чем проблема `:not(:only-child)` и есть ли альтернативные решения?

Comment: не очень понятно зачем вообще `:not(:only-child)`. Просто стили для класса если больше одного элемента, и `:only-child` если элемент один

Comment: Затем, что для одиночного элемента не срабатывает условие, если не отключть через not условие для нескольких

Answer (score 1):

Вроде получилось через `:only-of-type`:

```
[class*=pic] img:not(:only-of-type) {
flex-basis: calc(100% / 2); 
max-width: calc(100% / 2); 
}
```